# "Символ слитности" в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, golang

Моя задача удалить из строки все что связано с обозначением мегагерц/гигагерц.

Например из `'xxxx 3.7/4,3ghz xx'` или `'xxxx 2.30 ghz xx'` в `'xxxx  xx'`.
Условий задавать нужно целую кучу, но самое интересное для меня это - как можно добавить в набор символов "символ слитности", т.е. если есть `2.3ghz` и `2.3 ghz`, то как это обозначить в наборе `[...]`?

Пока делаю так

```
s = '2.30 ghz 2.30ghz'.lower()
re.sub("\d[.,]\d{1,2}ghz|\d[.,]\d{1,2} ghz", '', s)
```

Удваивать объём выражения из-за одного пробела не хочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один или более пробельных символов можно найти с помощью `\s*`. Вам даже необязательно использовать `.lower()`, если сделать выражение регистронезависимым с помощью модификатора `(?i)` или флага `re.I`.

```
import re
s = 'xxxx 2.30 ghz 2.30Ghz xx'
result = re.sub(r"\d[.,]\d{1,2}\s*ghz", '', s, flags=re.I)
print(result) # => xxxx   xx
```

См. [онлайн-демо кода](https://ideone.com/YqG0gR) и [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/mQBSOp/2/).

Обратите внимание, что `flags=re.I` используется с именем аргумента, иначе Python воспримет его как аргумент *count* и результаты будут непредсказуемы. Можно указать 0 в качестве третьего аргумента, тогда это будет не нужно:

```
re.sub(r"\d[.,]\d{1,2}\s*ghz", '', s, 0, re.I)
```

Для поиска чисел всё же лучше использовать выражение вроде

```
\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*ghz
```

**Подробности**

- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?:[.,]\d+)?` - 1 или 0 повторов последовательности точки или запятой, за которой следуют 1 и более цифр
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `ghz` - подстрока `ghz`